# Can't run remote PowerShell commands in custom CloudFormation AMI (WinServer 2012)

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

The issue I'm going to describe works OK on a stock Windows Server 2012 AMI from Amazon. I'm facing issues with a custom AMI.

I created a custom AMI for Windows Server 2012 by creating an image from an EC2 machine.

Just before creating the custom AMI, I used the Ec2ConfigServiceSetting.exe to make sure:

- The instance receives a new machine name based on its IP.
- The password of the user is changed on boot.
- The instance is provisioned using the script I have in place in UserData.

**I also shut down the instance using Sysprep from the Ec2ConfigServiceSetting** before creating the image for the custom AMI.

However, when I run a remote PowerShell command (from C# code, if it matters), it doesn't work. From C#-land, the command gets executed OK, but nothing happens in the machine.

Let's say my remote PS command launches a program in the remote machine (`agent.exe`). My script looks a little bit like:

```
Set-Location C:\path\in\disk
$env:Path = "C:\some\thing;" + $env:Path
C:\path\to\agent.exe --daemon
```

Once I log into the Ec2 instance, `agent.exe --daemon` is **NOT** running. However, **if I first log into the instance**, then run the remote PowerShell command, `agent.exe --daemon` **DOES** run.

This works perfectly with a stock AMI from Amazon, so I can only assume there's some configuration I'm missing for this to work (and, why does it work if I first log in using RDesktop?)

We found in the past some issues regarding SSL initialization without a user profile, so in our provisioning script (`UserData`) we do some things someone might consider shenanigans:

```
net user Administrator hardcoded-password
net user ec2-user hardcoded-password /add

$pwd = (ConvertTo-SecureString 'hardcoded-password' -AsPlainText -Force)
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('Administrator', $pwd)
Start-Process cmd -LoadUserProfile -Credential $cred
```